# URL JSON Response using Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an URL let's say (**http://json-data.com**) that returns a JSON response. I have to fetch this JSON data from this URL and save this data into an RDBMS.

So is there any method or class available from Django or REST Framework I can use to get the JSON data from an online URL in a variable so that I can then save it to RDBMS?

I am new to python and Djanog so maybe this question is naive. I would be grateful if you can assist me in any way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain what you aim to achieve, perhaps with a simple example?

Comment: yes sure. I have an URL that returns a JSON response. I have to fetch this JSON data from this URL and save this data into an RDBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a JSONField on your model if you just want to store raw JSON in your database. Have a look at the [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield)

If you want to store the returned values on a instance of your model, you could do something like this:

```
data = requests.get(url)
json_data = data.json()

# isolate the data key from the HTTP response object
item_list = json_data.get('data')

for item in item_list:
  name = item['name']
  age = item['age']

  # This will create a new instance for every object in the array from JSON response
  YourModel.objects.create(name=name, age=age)
```

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you very much for this. This is really helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON response data you are getting is structured in a certain way you can create you **own models** to match the data that you are getting. After that, you could create a script/command to fetch the data from the url and save it into your models.
It would be much cleaner and easier to access the database data this way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand what you are saying but just one more question. I know the JSON response that I am getting is structured and I have also created a model according to that. I have used 'json_data = requests.get(url)' to get the data from the URL. Now I am not sure how can I map this data to my models and save it.

Comment: you can take this example as a reference, JSON data contains multiple data of type      [{"name": 'XYZ', "age":"34"}, {"name": 'ABC', "age":"45"}]

Comment: You can basically create a management command (check in the docs), and write your logic there. You get the data from the Json response and create a new object from the model you’ve written. When done you just run object.save()